# listview of ASP.NET(web application)

Tags: asp.net, oracle, listview

i have placed four textbox inside the listview of web application. if i enter data in first textbox, its corresponding record should be fetched from oracle database and fetched record should be placed in 2,3,4 textbox.

Comment: Need more clarification. What you are actually need?

Comment: The listview is an asp .net control and a Windows Form control. Could you at least specify the domain of this question?

Comment: I think the tag asp.net control states that it is a web app.

Answer (score 1):

**[**TextBox.TextChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx)

[How to: Respond to Changes in a TextBox Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2589b44c%28VS.80%29.aspx)

***Edit:***

From your edit it would be better to use AJAX.

You can fetch data from oracle database from C# using the AJAX call and return the result to the response and display the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webforms you could use a WebMethod to invoke the query from javascript, you can see an example [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View7B75C93E-C8C9-4576-972B-2C3138DFC671.htm).

You could also just add a control that invokes a function server side and use the [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx) method of the ListView to obtain the value of your textbox. Also if you want the function/method to be called when the user stops typing you could use a jQuery plugin called typewatch you can find it [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TypeWatch). Also taking into account the WebMethod* attribute that I mentioned earlier in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the article [Complete ListView in ASP.NET 3.5](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/CompleteListView.aspx). This article shows how to place textboxes inside listview and edit the data in listview.

For Oracle connection in ASP.NET this article [Connecting to an Oracle Database Using ASP.NET—A Step-by-Step Tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/tutorials/article.php/c8477__2/) will definitly helps you